# Where I can find all sets of CFF font variations inside OTF fonts

Tags: fonts

I am currently working on my own font parser and for test purposes I want to have all CFF variations inside OTF font:

1. CFF with Type 1
2. CFF2 with Type 1
3. CFF2 with Type 2
4. CFF with TTF

Now I have only fonts containing CFF with Type 2.
Does anyone know where I can find other OTF variations?

Answer (score 0):

You could check the test suites in existing font parsing libraries. For example:

- [Fontkit tests](https://github.com/foliojs/fontkit/tree/master/test/data), with the appropriate license files
- [OpenType.js tests](https://github.com/opentypejs/opentype.js/tree/master/fonts)

Comment: There are only several otf fonts there by the links you mentioned. There mostly ttf fonts, which is good, but I need different variations of OTF fonts